# Terminal prompt unknown

Tags: terminal, prompt

There is 'unknown' at the terminal prompt and I don't know what it is referring to.

```
UNKNOWN:~ robertnash$ pwd
/Users/robertnash
UNKNOWN:~ robertnash$
```

Comment: the command 'hostname' generates UNKNOWN so ye think your right. what should I do?

Comment: @Archemar you need all of that information? I don't know what PS1 is.

Comment: [Why does OS X Terminal say 'unknown:~'](https://superuser.com/questions/633459/why-does-os-x-terminal-say-unknown)

Comment: @Archemar or you could just go and watch youtube instead right?

Answer (score 0):

[Copied from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/633459/why-does-os-x-terminal-say-unknown) via [Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395829/terminal-prompt-unknown#comment706381_395829) in order to potentially answer this question:

---

The `unknown:` part of the prompt is your computer's hostname.

Os X sets the hostname in quite a complicate way.

1. The name provided by the DHCP or BootP server for the primary IP address
2. The first name returned by a reverse DNS (address-to-name) query for the primary IP address
3. The local hostname (set in the Sharing pane of System Preferences)
4. The name localhost

In the usual case, the hostname is your `Computer Name` as defined in `Sharing`-Preference Pane. You can change it at `System Preferences` `->` `Sharing` `->` `Computer Name`

I can't help you with Terminal being unresponsive at this point. Please provide more information on how things got this way.